# How to copy values corresponding to the foreign key from another table to this table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `tblA` and `tblX`. In `tblA`, there is a foreign key `FKX` from `tblX`. I want to copy corresponding values of `StringColumn` to `strColCopy` column. It introduces redundancy but it's part of longer migrations process.

How can I access `tblX.StringColumn` cell for every single `tblA.FKX` cell?

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UPDATE` using `JOIN`

Solution for SQL Server:

```
UPDATE A 
SET A.strCol = X.StringColumn
FROM TblA A 
JOIN (SELECT FKX, strCol FROM TxlX GROUP BY FKX, strCol) AS X ON A.FKX = X.ID
```

Syntax for general `Update join` for SQL Server:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.columnToUpdate = [something]
FROM TABLEA a 
JOIN TABLEB b ON a.colA = b.colB
```

Solution for MySQL:

```
UPDATE TblA A 
JOIN (SELECT FKX ,strCol FROM TxlX GROUP BY FKX ,strCol)AS X
ON A.FKX = X.ID 
SET A.strCol = X.StringColumn
```

Syntax for general `Update join` for MySQL:

```
UPDATE TABLEA a 
JOIN TABLEB b ON a.colA = b.colB
SET a.columnToUpdate = [something]
```